# Angular2: query params not getting populated to global variables

Tags: angular, query-string

Am trying to extract the query params from url in `angular2` like:

```
this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe((params: Params) => {
     this.video0 = params['video0'];
     this.video1 = params['video1'];
     this.video2 = params['video2'];
     this.video3 = params['video3'];

    // alert("params are: "+ video0+", "+video1+", "+video2+", "+video3);
 });
```

And then I populate the global variables which I need to use to call another method inside `component` but am not getting the values in the global variables."

Everything is inside `ngOnInit` and this is how the entire code looks like:

```
video0: string;
video1: string;
video2: string;
video3: string;

constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) { }

ngOnInit() {


 this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe((params: Params) => {
      this.video0 = params['video0'];  
      this.video1 = params['video1'];
      this.video2 = params['video2'];
      this.video3 = params['video3'];

    // alert("params are: "+ video0+", "+video1+", "+video2+", "+video3);
 });
 this.sharedRequestPath = this.prepareSharedLinkRequestPath(this.video0,this.video1,this.video2,this.video3);  // all these values are undefined or null.
```

}

However, when I just do, `alert(params['video0'])` am getting the values.

**UPDATE**:

Changed the code to populate values:

```
this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe((params: Params) => {
     this.video0 = params['video0'];
     this.video1 = params['video1'];
     this.video2 = params['video2'];
     this.video3 = params['video3'];

    // alert("params are: "+ video0+", "+video1+", "+video2+", "+video3);
    this.sharedRequestPath = this.prepareSharedLinkRequestPath(this.video0,this.video1,this.video2,this.video3); 
    alert("sharedRequestPath is "+this.sharedRequestPath);

 });
```

However, I now see two alter statements loading, one without parameters and when I close it, other one loads with parameters. Why is that?

How can I achieve this? Not able to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Trying moving the below line inside the subscribe function:

this.sharedRequestPath = this.prepareSharedLinkRequestPath(this.video0,this.video1,this.video2,this.video3);

as you are trying to access onInit just before the subscribed data has come, but when you try to alert which is inside the subscribe method at that point the the subscribed data has come.

Comment: Though, values do get populated and I get the path, but backend API does not get these values as parameters

Comment: For sending queryParams you can leverage the URLSearchParams class for this:

getTranslation(lang: string): Observable<any> {
  let params = new URLSearchParams();
  params.set('param1', 'value1');

  return this.http.get(URL, { search: params });
}
This will result to an URL like this (parameters are added in the query string): http://...?param1=value1.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of your observable doesn't emit values before your function call (prepareSharedLinkRequestPath).

Call prepareSharedLinkRequestPath on your subsribe